# Reset / Ingnore non-zero exit code with fleet / systemd

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

I have a ***backup.service*** called every hour by a ***backup.timer***. Unfortunately the backup script running inside the container can complete *successful but with warnings* returning a non-zero exit code. So although everything may have worked, the container stops with a non-zero exitcode.
So the unit enters *failed* state in fleet.

And in that case it seems, the timer won't start this unit again, altough I didn't find anything in the systemd docs saying that.

To make it clear:
It's perfectly ok for me, to have the container stop with a non-zero exit code. But my timer then doesn't work.

I now could excapsulate that script into another which is then called als docker entrypoint. But I'll have to make sure that the output auf STDOUT and STDERR is somehow kept.

I also could run *sudo systemctl reset-failed* after the unit failed, but this seems to be a little hacky to me... (I tried that and in that case the timer ran the unit again. But it doesn't work as ExecStopPost-Task in the service file)

Is there any better way to make sure a that a unit

- doesn't enter failed state though it's returning non-zero, or
- reset it's state afterwards, or
- tell the timer to run that unit altough its status is *failed*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could prefix your command with `-`, then systemd ignores the failure and won't put the unit into a failed state. So, instead of

```
ExecStart=/path/to/your/command
```

Try

```
ExecStart=-/path/to/your/command
```

See [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) man page for more.

Comment: Believe it or not. I have about 15 service-files with exactly the `-` in my `ExecPre`-Tasks. I just didn't realized this as the solution... You made my day. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to ignore *some* return values, but still want some *others* to count to systemd as errors, you can specify them in the `[Service]` section of your .service file as a space-separated list to `SuccessExitStatus`, `RestartPreventExitStatus`, and `RestartForceExitStatus`. These also take signal names.

Reference: [man 5 systemd.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#SuccessExitStatus=)